# Does a sequence of differentiable functions has differentiable subsequential limits?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider a sequence $(f_n)$ of differentiable functions on $[0,1]$ which satisfy :

$$\vert f'_n(x) \leq 1 \vert \; \text{and} \; \vert f_n(x) \leq 1 \vert \; \forall x \in [0,1]$$
I showed that $(f_n)$ has subsequential limits in the sup metric.

Now I'm asked if those limits are necessarily differentiable ?
My intuition tells me that they are not but I cannot find a counter example. I thought about the deleted broom space or about some trigonometric functions but they do not work.

Does anyone have any ideas?